# Double precision to varchar postgresql

Tags: postgresql, casting, precision

I have to modify a table with fields of data types double precision to varchar, the alter was executed successfully, however the data change, and I can not understand what postgres does when it comes to making the conversion in both directions.

Postgres version: PostgreSQL 10.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN field_double_precision TYPE varchar;

--After the change this is my problem, new value is very different to old value

id     |old_value  |new_value              |
-------|-----------|-----------------------|
9009   |0.06       | 0.059999999999999998  |
9010   |0.56       | 0.56000000000000005   |
9011   |0.068      | 0.068000000000000005  |
9012   |0.568      | 0.56799999999999995   |
```

I understand that the values ​​change by approximation, but I must avoid this at all costs.

My test:

```
SELECT  CAST (0.059999999999999998 AS DOUBLE PRECISION) old_value;

old_value |
----------|
0.06      |

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  CAST (0.059999999999999998 AS double PRECISION)::VARCHAR new_value;

new_value            |
---------------------|
0.059999999999999998 |
```

I can keep my old and new value equal?, what happens when postgres formats the double precision to varchar?

Comment: On PostgreSQL 10.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1), 64-bit, your last statement gives me 0.06.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in 10.7.  Paste `create table` and `insert` statements that reproduce your issue.

Comment: On PostgreSQL 10.7 (Ubuntu 10.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0, 64-bit, your last statement also gives 0.06 `select cast(0.059999999999999998 AS double PRECISION)::VARCHAR new_value`

Comment: On Windows 10 PostgreSQL 10.7 compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit shows 0.06 for your last statement also.

Comment: In the first case `psql` is formatting the display of the number. In the second case, Postgres (the server) is formatting the number before converting it to a varchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you run the `ALTER TABLE` statement that changes the data type to `character varying`, make sure that you run the following statement:

`SET extra_float_digits = 0;`

That will cause PostgreSQL to suppress insignificant decimal digits when rendering a floating point number as a string.

Comment: If I `set extra_float_digits=1;`, I can reproduce the OP's *kind* of behavior, if not the identical behavior. But after `set extra_float_digits=0;` (the default on my server), PostgreSQL behaves like the OP wants. OP might also want to run `show extra_float_digits;` to see the current setting before making any changes.

Comment: That's what I said, isn't it? There are some drivers like JDBC that set `extra_float_digits` away from its default value 0.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe this worked for me, I got the desired result, when executing show extra_float_digits; this returned 3, so included partially significant digits according to the documentation, by setting the parameter to 0, the data is kept as entered, I came to think it was my client's problem (DBeaver version 4.1.2 to see the previous answers). regards

Answer (score 1):

According to the Postgresql documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html) Double Precision have the following behavior..

> The data types real and double precision are inexact,
>   variable-precision numeric types. In practice, these types are usually
>   implementations of IEEE Standard 754 for Binary Floating-Point
>   Arithmetic (single and double precision, respectively), to the extent
>   that the underlying processor, operating system, and compiler support
>   it.
>
> Inexact means that some values cannot be converted exactly to the
>   internal format and are stored as approximations, so that storing and
>   retrieving a value might show slight discrepancies. Managing these
>   errors and how they propagate through calculations is the subject of
>   an entire branch of mathematics and computer science and will not be
>   discussed here, except for the following points:
>
> - If you require exact storage and calculations (such as for monetary    amounts), use the numeric type instead.
> - If you want to do complicated calculations with these types for    anything important, especially if you rely on certain behavior in
>     boundary cases (infinity, underflow), you should evaluate the
>     implementation carefully.
> - Comparing two floating-point values for equality might not always    work as expected.

What about casting the double precision to a numeric and then casting that numeric to a varchar?